# Change form input attribute 'name' to 'data-encrypted-name'

Tags: django, forms, braintree

This was a tricky question to title, so please read before assuming its a duplicate :).

I'm using [Braintree Payments](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) on a Django site, and the [payment form](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/python/guide/getting_paid#payment_form) html needs to look like this for the credit card number:

```
<input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" data-encrypted-name="number" />
```

mine currently looks like this:

```
<input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" name="number">
```

Can I somehow rename `name` to `data-encrypted-name`?  Alternatively, can I hide/remove the `name` attribute altogether?  If so, I could then easily add a custom attribute for the Braintree-friendly attribute:

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    ...snip...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

         self.fields['number'].widget.attrs['data-encrypted-name'] = "number"
```

FYI I tried this in the `__init__` but no luck:

```
         self.fields['number'].widget.attrs['name'] = None
```

Per [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/python/guide/getting_paid#payment_form):

> IMPORTANT: Do not use the name attribute for any fields that capture
>   sensitive payment information such as the credit card number or CVV.
>   Removing this attribute prevents them from hitting your server in
>   plain text and so reduces your PCI compliance scope.

Also, I'm using django [crispy forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms), so I'd prefer to solve this in my `forms.py` and not in the template with html tweaks in order to keep it DRY.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define a custom widget class inheriting from whatever widget type your `numbers` field defaults to (`TextInput`, judging from the tag you're showing) and override its `build_attrs` method.

I'd do it something like this:

```
class SensitiveTextInput(TextInput):
    def build_attrs(self, extra_attrs=None, **kwargs):
        attrs = super(SensitiveTextInput, self).build_attrs(extra_attrs, **kwargs)
        if 'name' in attrs:
            attrs['data-encrypted-name'] = attrs['name']
            del attrs['name']
        return attrs
```

If you need to do this for more than a handful of widget types you could abstract this into a mixin.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I added exactly what you have here, but also had to add `from django.forms.widgets import TextInput`.  Also, my form field now looks like: `number = CreditCardField(required = True, label = "Card Number", widget = SensitiveTextInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'off', 'size': 20}))`.  CreditCardField is just a custom field I grabbed from [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/907/).

Comment: Actually, I can't use the `CreditCardField` mentioned above and all of its fancy validation checks.  The Braintree js encypts the CC number and CVV fields before submitting the form, so the validation checks fail.

Comment: @Banjer so did you end up using a regular `forms.CharField` instead of the `CreditCardField`?

Comment: Useful. This is great for integrating Stripe (Stripe.com - hopefully that'll help Google searches)

Comment: @teewuane sorry, just saw your comment.  I ended up using CharField.  It looks like `number = forms.CharField(required=True, label = "Card Number", widget = SensitiveTextInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'off', 'size': 20}))`