# Change form input attribute 'name' to 'data-encrypted-name' in Rails forms

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, braintree

[Change form input attribute 'name' to 'data-encrypted-name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116917/change-form-input-attribute-name-to-data-encrypted-name/18117395) discusses Django, but this question is about Rails.

I created a form in Rails to handle credit card payments with Braintree. However, the encryption doesn't work because Rails adds name attributes to the forms. As per the [Braintree Docs](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/guide/getting_paid#payment_form), I want to replace the name attributes with `data-encrypted-name` attributes. How do I do this?

This (nested) form helper:

```
<%= cc.text_field :number %>
```

..creates the following element:

```
 <input id="credit_card_number" name="credit_card[number]" size="30" type="text">
```

How do I replace `name` with `data-encrypted-name`?

Comment: Anything beginning with `data-` is a programmer-specific extension. You probably have got ahold of a Django app that uses JavaScript to encrypt a credit card number, and to replace the name and value with their encrypted versions before sending them. I have done credit cards before, and you don't need this. If you use HTTPS, and if your user is careful with their browser and computer, then your numbers are secure. Oh, also, Braintree's libraries & example code are the best in the business...

Comment: @Phlip, the Braintree docs say to use `data-encrypted-name`, I'm just trying to do that in Rails forms.  https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/guide/getting_paid#payment_form

Comment: What's the model look like?

Comment: `cc.text_field :number, 'data-encrypted-name' => 'something'`

Comment: @JustusDannyEapen, technically there is no model (for credit card transactions), but I'm using the Braintree-Rails-Gem to kinda pretend there's one https://github.com/lyang/braintree-rails

Comment: @Phlip, but Rails still creates a name attribute, besides the data-encrypted one.

Comment: then you are down to @beautifulcoder 's answer; the more custom your HTML, the less you can use Rails's magical tags. If text_field_tag insists on adding a `name=""`, then just write the raw HTML yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Try `text_field_tag` like

```
<%= text_field_tag 'credit_card[data-encrypted-name]', size: 30 %>
```

You may also assign a value, for example

```
<%= text_field_tag 'credit_card[data-encrypted-name]', cc.number, size: 30 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Philp's answer works.  Given Braintree's docs, the following in development mode runs as intended:

```
c.text_field  :number, 'data-encrypted-name' => "number"
```